# WPF Toolkit Charting and IndependentValueBinding, IndependentValuePath

Tags: wpf, binding, charts, wpftoolkit

I'm facing a problem with the charting engine from the WPF toolkit.

I haven't moved the data to a proper object model, so the `ItemSource` is backed with a `DataView`.

First attempt

```
<chartingToolkit:ScatterSeries x:Name="TargetSeries" 
  DataPointStyle="{StaticResource TargetStyle}"  
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TargetSeriesData}"
  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=TargetSeries_X}" 
  DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=TargetSeries_X}" />
```

This crashes because I believe the bindings are considered as the values to the plot or some sort of mismatch.

Second attempt

```
<chartingToolkit:ScatterSeries x:Name="TargetSeries" 
  DataPointStyle="{StaticResource TargetStyle}" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TargetSeriesData}"
  IndependentValuePath="{Binding Path=TargetSeries_X}"
  DependentValuePath="{Binding Path=TargetSeries_X}" />
```

This crash happens during the initialization step because the Path properties aren't backed with dependency properties and therefore cannot be bound.

Third attempt

```
<chartingToolkit:ScatterSeries x:Name="TargetSeries" 
  DataPointStyle="{StaticResource TargetStyle}"  
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TargetSeriesData}"
  IndependentValuePath="targetFooXColumnName" 
  DependentValuePath="targetFooYColumnName" />
```

Now this works!
But I wanted to use the binding so I can switch from using the `targetFooXColumnName` to the `targetFooBarXColumnName`. So this solution will cause a whole lot of hacky looking code to switch the Path manually.

Is there a way to fix this? Can I use some sort of converter to get the Binding properties to correctly pull the data from the columns in the DataView?

Thanks,
Joel

Comment: The code's been completely rewritten over the last 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

I think your application crashing on reason is "you haven't moved the data to a proper object model"

i can try Binding in ScatterSeries its working with out crashes: Like

```
<Grid Name="grid_Sample" Loaded="grid_Sample_Loaded">
    <DVC:Chart Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10" Name="mcChart"
       Width="400" Height="250"
       Background="LightSteelBlue">
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:ScatterSeries x:Name="TargetSeries" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding sampleList}"
      IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=TargetSeries_X}"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=TargetSeries_Y}">
    </DVC:ScatterSeries>
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
</Grid>

 private void grid_Sample_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sampleList = new ObservableCollection<SampleTest>() { 
            new SampleTest(){TargetSeries_X=20,TargetSeries_Y=50},
        new SampleTest(){TargetSeries_X=25,TargetSeries_Y=60},
        new SampleTest(){TargetSeries_X=30,TargetSeries_Y=50},
        new SampleTest(){TargetSeries_X=40,TargetSeries_Y=60}
        };
        ((ScatterSeries)mcChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = sampleList; 
    }
```

According to My Knowledge please try with Proper model for binding ItemsSource to ScatterSeries.